Error while adding page numbers using pdfcpu
I am using PDFCPU.exe to add page numbers to a large batch of PDFs. Looks like some of the PDFs are processing correctly during the optimization portion.

here is my command:
"C:\Temp\PDFCPU\pdfcpu.exe" stamp add -mode text -- "Page %p of %P" "scale:0.35 abs, pos:bc, rot:0" "C:\Temp\XXXX.pdf" "C:\Temp\XXXX_100.pdf"

Is there a parameter to skip the opitmization process?

are we saying its probably issue with the pdf itself?

i appreciate the explanation, but is there any actionable? i don't have technical pdf knowledge enough to figure out a remedy.  what are some troubleshooting steps do you think I should take?

It could be a problem with the PDF itself because the optimization part could potentially re-compress existing streams (I haven't looked at the code, though). If you can provide the PDF, you will get help much faster.
